# is it ok to use formview instead of updateview, createview in Django?

Tags: django, django-generic-views

so I'm new here in django and have already get the point of some `generic views` but it really gives me a hard time to understand the `UpdateView`, `CreateView` and `DeleteView` all information that I search still not giving me a point on how to use them. So I have a form registration which have username and password but they are in different `table` or `model` to save; you may take a look on the `forms.py`, And trying `UpdateView` its giving me only an error to my project. So as I found in some forums, i can't use `UpdateView` to a `foreign key` table for its looking only a `primary key` So instead of using them I use `FormView` replacing by the 3 `generic view` for now. Is it ok to use the `FormView` as an option aside the 3 `generic view`?

Here is my source code.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class UserCredentialForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label = 'Email', widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_login_username',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'autocomplete': 'off',
        }
    ), required = False)
    password = forms.CharField(label = 'Password', widget = forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_login_password',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ), required = False)

class UserInfoForm(forms.Form):
    year  = {}
    days  = {}
    month = {
        '': '---------',
        'Jan': 'January', 'Feb': 'February', 'Mar': 'March',
        'Apr': 'April', 'May': 'May', 'Jun': 'June', 'Jul': 'July',
        'Aug': 'August', 'Sep': 'September', 'Oct': 'October',
        'Nov': 'November', 'Dec': 'December'
    }
    gender = {
        'Male': 'Male', 'Female': 'Female',
        'Not Specify': 'Not Specify'
    }

    year[''] = '---------'
    days[''] = '---------'

    from datetime import datetime

    for i in range((int(datetime.now().strftime('%Y'))), (1920 - 1), -1):
        year[i] = i

    for i in range(1, (31 + 1)):
        days[i] = i

    password = forms.CharField(label = 'Password', widget = forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_password',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Password'
        }
    ), required = True)
    email = forms.EmailField(label = 'Email', widget = forms.EmailInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_email',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Email',
            'autocomplete': 'off'
        }
    ), required = True)
    firstname = forms.CharField(label = 'Firstname', widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_firstname',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Firstname',
            'autocomplete': 'off'
        }
    ), required = True)
    lastname = forms.CharField(label = 'Lastname', widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_lastname',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Lastname',
            'autocomplete': 'off'
        }
    ), required = True)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Gender', widget = forms.Select(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_gender',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ), choices = list(gender.items()), required = False)
    birthdate_year = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Year', widget = forms.Select(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_birthyear',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ), choices = list(year.items()), required = True)
    birthdate_day = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Day', widget = forms.Select(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_day',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ), choices = list(days.items()), required = True)
    birthdate_month = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Month', widget = forms.Select(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_month',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ), choices = list(month.items()), required = True)
```

This view file is from the `login app`:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import (
    UserModel,
)
from django.db.models import (
    Q,
)
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import (
    make_password, check_password
)
from django.views.generic.base import (
    TemplateView,
)
from django.views.generic import (
    FormView,
)
from .formprocess import (
    UserCredentialForm, UserInfoForm,
)
from .forms import (
    UserCredentialForm, UserInfoForm,
)

# Create your views here.

class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'login/views/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        loginform    = UserCredentialForm(self.request.GET or None)
        registerform = UserInfoForm(self.request.GET or None)
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['loginform']    = loginform
        context['registerform'] = registerform
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        mForm = UserCredentialForm(self.request.POST)
        if mForm.is_valid():
            mUsername  = mForm.cleaned_data['username']
            mPassword  = mForm.cleaned_data['password']
            mUserModel = UserModel.objects.filter(
                Q(email = mUsername) | Q(username = mUsername)
            )
            # Check if there is fetched data from UserModel.
            if not mUserModel:
                return redirect(reverse_lazy('login'))
            else:
                # Get password from query result.
                # Check if password valid or not.
                db_password = ''
                for obj in mUserModel:
                    db_password = obj.password
                if check_password(mPassword, db_password):
                    return redirect(reverse_lazy('site'))
                else:
                    return redirect(reverse_lazy('login'))
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(mForm)
            )

# Handle forms

def signup(request):
    return RegisterFormProcess(request).do_task()

def logout(request):
    return redirect('login')
```

and for the signup process method here it is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models import (
    Q,
)
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import (
    make_password, check_password,
)
from .models import (
    UserModel, UserInfoModel,
)
from .forms import (
    UserCredentialForm, UserInfoForm,
)

class RegisterFormProcess:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def do_task(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            mRegisterForm = UserInfoForm(self.request.POST)
            if mRegisterForm.is_valid():
                # Collect data
                mFirstname = mRegisterForm.cleaned_data['firstname']
                mLastname  = mRegisterForm.cleaned_data['lastname']
                mEmail     = mRegisterForm.cleaned_data['email']
                mPassword  = mRegisterForm.cleaned_data['password']
                mGender    = mRegisterForm.cleaned_data['gender']
                mBYear     = mRegisterForm.cleaned_data['birthdate_year']
                mBDay      = mRegisterForm.cleaned_data['birthdate_day']
                mBMonth    = mRegisterForm.cleaned_data['birthdate_month']
                # Check if email is already exists.
                isEmaiExists = UserModel.objects.filter(email = mEmail)
                if not isEmaiExists:
                    # Validate password length.
                    if len(mPassword) < 4:
                        messages.error(self.request, 'Password is too short to use.')
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('login'))
                    else:
                        # Save user information and move to user profile settings.
                        from datetime import datetime
                        mUserModel = UserModel()
                        mUserModel.email     = mEmail
                        mUserModel.password  = make_password(mPassword)
                        mUserModel.status    = 'active'
                        mUserModel.date_join = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                        mUserModel.authority = 1
                        mUserModel.save()
                        mUserInfoModel = UserInfoModel()
                        mUserInfoModel.users     = mUserModel
                        mUserInfoModel.firstname = mFirstname
                        mUserInfoModel.lastname  = mLastname
                        mUserInfoModel.birthdate = f'{mBMonth} {mBDay}, {mBYear}'
                        mUserInfoModel.gender    = mGender
                        mUserInfoModel.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('site'))
                else:
                    messages.error(self.request, 'Email is already in use.')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('login'))
        else:
            mRegisterForm = UserInfoForm()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('login'))
```

and here is the view `site app` file:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from mediasocialplatform.wraps import login_required
from django.views.generic.base import (
    TemplateView,
)
from django.views.generic import (
    FormView,
)
from login.models import (
    UserInfoModel,
)
from login.forms import (
    UserInfoForm,
)

# Create your views here.

class SiteIndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'site/views/index.html'

# THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO USE THE UPDATEVIEW
class SettingsProfileView(FormView):
    template_name       = 'site/views/settingsprofile.html'
    form_class          = UserInfoForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        mForm          = self.form_class(self.request.GET or None)
        kwargs['form']   = mForm
        kwargs['object'] = UserInfoModel.objects.filter(
            users_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        )
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

Answer (score 1):

UpdateView, CreateView and DeleteView are there to make your life easy. To basically make easy forms and only include or exclude fields that you do or don't want to see, and the rest is taken care of by Django. That's the benefit.

Comment: so how can I handle multiple model and forms in 1 `Form`? lets say I have a registration form with widgets but there are some widgets must save in different model, like above example the username and password must save in `UserModel` and other information will be save in `UserInfoModel`. how can you Modify the user information only and get the datas since `UpdateView` require only a `primary key` and not `foreign key`? and also when I try to use `UpdateView` it gives me error difficult to find out the solutions. can you give atleast a good example?